# changing scroll-based fade on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've linked the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tiffanyh/0cw93bo3/8/) to the code i'm working with here. The fade-scroll function is working beautifully. I just want to be able to change the rate of fade based on screen size. Essentially, I need it to fade sooner than that on smaller screens (mobile/tablet) because of changes in size in my media queries.

**Ex: be able to tweak these numbers...**

```
      $('#one').css({'opacity':(( **300**-scroll )/ **300**)+0.4});
```

**based on screen size.**

I was thinking an if/else condition, but I'm super new to JS and jQuery and can't figure it out. Thank you.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
          $('#one').css({'opacity':(( 300-scroll )/ 300)+0.4});
          $('#two').css({'opacity':(( 600-scroll )/ 300)+0.4});
          $('#three').css({'opacity':(( 1100-scroll )/ 300)+0.4});
          $('#four').css({'opacity':(( 1400-scroll )/ 300)+0.4});
          $('#five').css({'opacity':(( 1700-scroll )/ 300)+0.4});
           
        });
```

```css
#one{
  margin: 2em auto 2em auto;
  padding-top: 1em;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: coral;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  }
  
  #two{
  margin: 2em auto 2em auto;
  padding-top: 1em;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: coral;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  }
  
  #three{
  margin: 2em auto 2em auto;
  padding-top: 1em;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: coral;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  }
  
  #four{
  margin: 2em auto 2em auto;
  padding-top: 1em;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: coral;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  }
  
  #five{
  margin: 2em auto 2em auto;
  padding-top: 1em;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: coral;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="one">
first fade element
</div>
<div id="two">
second fade element
</div>
<div id="three">
third fade element
</div>
<div id="four">
fourth fade element
</div>
<div id="five">
fifth fade element
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: Thanks! I kept googling it, and lurking, so I decided to join. Maybe one day I'll be good enough at this stuff to contribute haha.

Comment: lol, you asked a good question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check for window width inside your scroll event

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if($(this).width() > 500){ // if window width bigger than 500  change 500 with width you need
       $('#one').css({'opacity':(( 300-scroll )/ 300)+0.4});
       $('#two').css({'opacity':(( 600-scroll )/ 300)+0.4});
       $('#three').css({'opacity':(( 1100-scroll )/ 300)+0.4});
       $('#four').css({'opacity':(( 1400-scroll )/ 300)+0.4});
       $('#five').css({'opacity':(( 1700-scroll )/ 300)+0.4});
     }else{
            //if less than 500
     }  
});
```

Comment: That's exactly it. Thank you!

Comment: @tiffanyaych Very Good Luck :)

Comment: @tiffanyaych this is more thing .. if you creating a responsive template you may need to add resize event as well so you can use it like  $(window).on('scroll resize' , function(){.......}); .. Good Luck :)